# Convert NSArray to NSDictionary for sectioning

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, sections

I have this NSArray:

```
{name="LOBSTER",photo="prawn.jpg"},{name="COW", photo"cow_grass.png"},...so on
```

And I want to create section in the UITableView, so I need a dictionary like this:

```
{L=(name="Lobster";photo="prawn.jpg"),C=(name="COW"; photo="cow_grass.png"),...so on}
```

Could you please help me tell me how to do it? Thank you.

This is how I add my array:

```
animalsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
      //Loop through our JsonDict
      long countArray = [[dataDict valueForKey:@"animal"]count];
      for (int i = 0; i < countArray ; i++)
         {
         NSString * cName = [[[dataDict valueForKey:@"animal"]objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey: @"name"];
         NSString * cPhoto = [[[dataDict valueForKey:@"animal"]objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey: @"photo"];

         [animalArray addObject:[[Animals alloc]initWithName:cName andPhoto:cPhoto]];
```

Comment: What you want is a dictionary of arrays of dictionaries.  What you show above is a dictionary of I don't know what.

Comment: @edward..Refer my updated answer..
You will get number of sections..using my code..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**

> I now see that you want an object of type `Animal` instead of an `NSDictionary`. The line of code which was `animal[@"name"]` needs to be what ever accessor method to get the name. I updated my code to guess that you need `animal.name`.

Do you want a full index (A dictionary with all the values 'A'–'Z' even if most keys have an empty array)?

```
- (NSDictionary *)fullIndexOfAnimalsFromAnimals:(NSArray *)animals
{
    NSMutableDictionary *result = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

    // Create a key for each letter of the alphabet.
    for (char ch = 'A'; ch <= 'Z'; ++ch) {
        NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", ch];
        result[key] = [NSArray array];
    }

    // Add all the animals keyed by the first character of their name.
    for (Animal *animal in animals) {
        NSString *key = [animal.name substringToIndex:1] uppercaseString];
        result[key] = [result[key] arrayByAddingObject:animal];
    }

    return [result copy]; // NSMutableDictionary * to NSDictionary *
}
```

Do you want a partial index (A dictionary with only the keys that have values)?

```
- (NSDictionary *)partialIndexOfAnimalsFromAnimals:(NSArray *)animals
{
    NSMutableDictionary *result = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

    // Add all the animals keyed by the first character of their name.
    for (Animal *animal in animals) {
        NSString *key = [animal.name substringToIndex:1] uppercaseString];
        NSArray *value = result[key];
        if (value == nil) {
            result[key] = [NSArray arrayWithObject:animal]; // Create new array
        } else {
            result[key] = [value arrayByAddingObject:animal]; // Add to existing
        }
    }

    return [result copy]; // NSMutableDictionary * to NSDictionary *
}
```

---

As a second update, there is something odd.

```
[animalArray addObject:[[Animals alloc] initWithUser_id:cUser_id
                                                andName:cName
                                                 andNik:cNik
                                           andJob_title:cJob_title
                                               andPhone:cPhone
                                             andRoom_no:cRoom_no
                                               andPhoto:cPhoto]];
```

Is storying `Animal *` in `animalArray`, but the error message you have seems to indicate that `NSMutuableArray *` objects are being stored in `animalArray`.

Comment: I get an error said that Expected method to read dictionary element not found on object of type 'NSMutableArray *' What should I do? @JefferyThomas

Comment: @Edward Where are you getting that error, none of the example code uses NSMutableArray.

Comment: in animal[@"name"] @JefferyThomas

Comment: I figured out that maybe your code isn't complete yet. It should be for ("NSSomething" in animals). I tried to change it to NSString but it still said an error: Expected method to read dictionary element not found on object of type 'NSString*' @JefferyThomas

Comment: Sorry, that one should be[animalArray addObject:[[Animals alloc] initWithName:cName andPhoto:cPhoto]];

Answer (score 2):

Try below code..

```
NSMutableDictionary *finalResultDict=[NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

    for(NSDictionary *wildanimals in animalsarray)
    {

    NSString *key=[[wildanimals[@"name"] substringToIndex:1] uppercaseString];

    if([wildanimals[@"name"] hasPrefix:key])
    {
       [finalResultDict setValue: wildanimals forKey:key] ;
    }
    }
```

You can set number of sections by allKeysArray count as below

```
NSArray * allKeysArray = [finalResultDict allKeys];
NSLog(@"Count : %d", [finalResultDict count]);
```

Hope it helps you...!

Comment: error on if function said --> Non-ASCII characters are not allowed outside of literals and identifiers. And suggest me to delete the 'ha' in hasPrefix @Vidhyanand900

Comment: It clear the previous error but now it cannot recognise setValue for animal. What i need to put in there? @Vidhyanand900

Comment: Thanks @Vidhyanand900 now there is no error. But when i run the program it said -[Animal objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10a6df8b0. Maybe because how I addObject to my Array. Please read my edited question

Answer (score 1):

Hope below is the code you are looking for.

```
NSArray *currentArray = ...

// New dictionary object to hold the grouped results.
NSMutableDictionary *dictionaryWithSections = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

for (NSDictionary *dictionary in currentArray) {
    NSString *section = [[[dictionary objectForKey:@"name"] substringToIndex:1] uppercaseString];

    // Check whether section already exits.
    if ([dictionaryWithSections objectForKey:section]) {
        [[dictionaryWithSections objectForKey:section] addObject:dictionary];
    } else {
        NSMutableArray *sectionData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:dictionary];
        [dictionaryWithSections setObject:sectionData forKey:section];
    }
}
```

dictionaryWithSections is the new dictionary you get with grouping.
`[dictionaryWithSections allKeys]` will return all the section titles you want. i.e. L, C.. etc.

Comment: I got error said --> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Animals objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x11195b0e0'

Comment: What is the code you are trying? is it from this answer or the other answer?

Answer (score 0):

Take Dictionary and set object for key

```
 NSMutableArray *arr;
NSMutableDictionary *dict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[dict setObject:arr forKey:@"L"];
```